# how to refresh my qr code generator in imageview

Tags: android, qr-code

I want to ask about how to refresh imageview in qr code generator, I have created a qr code generator with time picker and number picker and I want to know how can i refresh my qr code generator because when I tried to redo it, it show the same qr code when i change some thing on the time picker and number picker.

qr code generator code:

```
public class QRCode extends Activity {

    Button doneBtn;
    ImageView qrIv;
    TextView minute;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.qrcode);
        minute = findViewById(R.id.set_minute);
        doneBtn = findViewById(R.id.btnDone);
        qrIv = findViewById(R.id.ivQr);

        doneBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(QRCode.this, MainMenu.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String data = intent.getStringExtra("data");

        MultiFormatWriter multiFormatWriter = new MultiFormatWriter();
        try {
            BitMatrix bitMatrix = multiFormatWriter.encode(data, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 400, 400);
            BarcodeEncoder barcodeEncoder = new BarcodeEncoder();
            Bitmap bitmap = barcodeEncoder.createBitmap(bitMatrix);
            qrIv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            InputMethodManager manager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            manager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(minute.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);
        } catch (WriterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

number picker and time picker code:

```
public class Visitor extends Activity {
    
    String def = "00 ";
    TimePicker timeTp;
    NumberPicker minNp;
    String[] minutesArray;
    Button createBtn;
    Integer id = 12345;
    String space = " ";
    String paddedId;

    StringBuilder spaceId = new StringBuilder();

    String newId;

    String data;


    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.visitor);
        minNp = findViewById(R.id.npMin);
        minNp.setMaxValue(5);
        minNp.setMinValue(0);
        minutesArray = new String[] {"15","30","45","60","75","90"};
        minNp.setDisplayedValues(minutesArray);
        timeTp = findViewById(R.id.tp);
        createBtn = findViewById(R.id.btnCreate);
        timeTp.setIs24HourView(true);

        paddedId = String.format("%08d", id);

        for(int i = 0; i < paddedId.length(); i += 2) {
            spaceId.append(paddedId.substring(i, i + 2)).append(" ");
        }

        newId = spaceId.toString().trim();

        Map<String,String> parameters = new HashMap<String,String>();
        int value = minNp.getValue();
        parameters.put("mins", Integer.toString(value));

        data = def + newId + space + String.format("%02d", timeTp.getHour()) + space + String.format("%02d", timeTp.getMinute()) + space + minutesArray[minNp.getValue()] + space;

        createBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Visitor.this, QRCode.class).putExtra("data", data));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could involve loading the [image](https://peoplesgamegift.xyz/doubleu-casino-free-chips-promo/) from a file or converting it to a drawable object, depending on the framework or programming language you're using.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).